# Where to find more free space so system disk on server 2003?

Tags: windows, operating-system, system, windows-server-2003

System disk is runnig out of disk space.

Should I delete all *.tmp files from windows directory?
Should I delete all $NtUninstall*$ directories?

What else can I delete from system folders?

Basic things like temprary internet files etc have deleted, basic log files are deleted. All unused application have been removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't plan to ever back down from any of the hotfix / service pack then yes. Just don't delete the software distribution folder \WINDOWS\$hf_mig$

You could also burn them to CD just in case.

Comment: All of those have been done. now I'am seeking new ones to delete like those tmp files on windows directory (15 000 files,3,3gb) ? and can I delete those uninstall directories (277 dirs)?

Comment: tmp yes, uninstall directories too.